# Unable to change X/Y axis value in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the following code to  create a D3 figure for.In This,I am trying to plot a few weather related data.In the code ,I am trying change the axis value but unable to do it. It is getting fixed to the default value I have provided in the beginning. Can someone please help me with it. The dataset I am using is json data(link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/13-unvzxvjmFWVgfSKRJObZJc81VriyIf/view?usp=sharing).

following is the code I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">



<style>
body {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 28px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,       //900
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;      //450

// setup fill color
    var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([-15, 30])
                            .range(["blue","red"]);

// add the graph canvas to the body of the webpage
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// add the tooltip area to the webpage
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);
var selectData = [ { "text" : "meantempm" },
                   { "text" : "meanpressurem" },
                   { "text" : "meanwindspdm" },
                   { "text" : "humidity" },
                   ]
   var body = d3.select('body');
// load data
d3.json("weatherdata.json", function(error, data) {

  // change string (from CSV) into number format
    data.forEach(function(d) {//to check the utility
    d.meanwindspdm = +d.history.dailysummary[0].meanwindspdm;
    d.meantempm = +d.history.dailysummary[0].meantempm;
    d.meanpressurem = +d.history.dailysummary[0].meanpressurem;
    d.humidity = +d.history.dailysummary[0].humidity;

//    console.log(d);
  });


// setup x
var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return (d.meanpressurem);}), //given
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(xExtent).range([0, width]), // value -> display   //given 
    xValue = function(d) { return ((d.meanpressurem));}, // data -> value
    xMap = function(d) { return xScale(d.meanpressurem);}, // data -> display
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom"); //given

// setup y
var yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return (d.meantempm);}),
    yValue = function(d) { return d.meantempm;}, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(yExtent).range([height, 0]), // value -> display
    yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d));}, // data -> display
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

//new addition
  // Select X-axis Variable
  var defs = body.append('defs')
    .text('X-Axis:')
  var yInput = body.append('select')
      .attr('id','xSelect')
      .on('change',xChange)
    .selectAll('option')
      .data(selectData)
      .enter()
    .append('option')
      .attr('value', function (d) { return d.text }) ///check
      .text(function (d) { return d.text ;})
  //body.append('br')

  // Select Y-axis Variable
  var span = body.append('defs')
      .text('Y-Axis: ')
  var yInput = body.append('select')
      .attr('id','ySelect')
       .on('change',yChange)
    .selectAll('option')
      .data(selectData)
      .enter()
    .append('option')
      .attr('value', function (d) { return d.text })//check
      .text(function (d) { return d.text ;})
  body.append('br')

//new addition upto 

  // x-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr('id','xAxisLabel')
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("meanwindspdm");

  // y-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr('id','yAxisLabel')
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("meantempm");

  // draw dots
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.meantempm)}) 
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", .9);
          tooltip.html(d.history.date.pretty + "<br/> (" + xValue(d) 
            + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      });

  // draw legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(colorScale.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  // draw legend colored rectangles
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 10)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", colorScale);

  // draw legend text
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 16)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d;})
      // new addiiton/////////

    function yChange() {
    var value = this.value // get the new y value
    yScale // change the yScale
      .domain([
        d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return +d.history.dailysummary[0][value] })]),
        d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return +d.history.dailysummary[0][value] })])
        ])
    yAxis.scale(yScale) // change the yScale
    d3.select('#yAxis') // redraw the yAxis
      .transition().duration(50)
      .call(yAxis)
    d3.select('#yAxisLabel') // change the yAxisLabel
      .text(value)    
    d3.selectAll('circle') // move the circles
      .transition().duration(50)
         .delay(50)
      //.delay(function (d,i) { return i*100})
        .attr('cy',function (d) { return yScale(+d.history.dailysummary[0][value]) })
  }

  function xChange() {
    var value = this.value   // get the new x value
    console.log(value);
    console.log(data);
    xScale // change the xScale
        .domain([
        d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) {console.log( +d.history.dailysummary[0][value] ) ; return +d.history.dailysummary[0][value] })]), 
        d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return +d.history.dailysummary[0][value] })])
        ])

    xAxis.scale(xScale) // change the xScale //issue here I guess`enter code here`
    d3.select('#xAxis') // redraw the xAxis
      .transition().duration(50)
      .call(xAxis)
    d3.select('#xAxisLabel') // change the xAxisLabel
      .transition().duration(50)
      .text(value)
    d3.selectAll('circle') // move the circles
      .transition().duration(50)
      .delay(50)
      //.delay(function (d,i) { return i*100})
        .attr('cx',function (d) {  return xScale(+d.history.dailysummary[0][value]); })

  }
      // new addiiton upto/////////
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your code correctly you are trying to select and element with id `xAxis` or `yAxis`, which you have not specified in the code given, which you gave

```
.attr("class", "x axis")
```

Try using `d3.select(".x")` and `d3.select(".y")` instead of `d3.select("#xAxis")` and `d3.select("#yAxis")`.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. It helped. i did the two mistakes..1) I added the wrong class and forgot to add the id of axis. Now it works.. I have another issue. In the picture you can see that the x-axis label appears to be not in the right position. Do you have any idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: link for the pic:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/13-unvzxvjmFWVgfSKRJObZJc81VriyIf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That links to a json file.

Comment: My mistake: this is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pl_rW472a3-jB58HmFLZyY57oZIDa-Wf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have the x location for the xAxis label set to your chart width, try subtracting margin.right. Where are you trying to get it?

Comment: I am trying get it at the beginning,right under the starting of X-axis. Something like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z4J6CBRYaKY1L0QISgqHNGFQUTAAXOxq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Adding some CSS to get them positioned correctly is probably the easiest way to do it. Or you could set an x position for the select menus as well `.attr("x", width/2)` will set them in the middle